# Tools/Tips with exploring a foreign JavaScript applications architecture

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modeling

I recently starting working at a new company, and been assigned an VB.NET application with a significant amount of JavaScript.

I find exploring complied languages written in object orientated fashions to be much much easier to wrap my head around.

This application pretty much does everything on the server side, and not only do i find JavaScript a lot harder to learn someone else's code, but there is also no comments, and cryptically named objects. External JavaScript objects are being used/called from all over the place, and i seldom can find where they live, or how they were populated with data.

There was no UML, or structural diagram, or documentation detailing the structure of the application at this level, and it's developer has left the company.

I could use a little help from some season JavaScript gurus, and how/what tools they use to help them explore JavaScript systems.

Thanks.

Comment: You might find `firebug` useful. You can use it to debug the JavaScript code, inspect things at runtime, the results of AJAX calls,  etc. It will not necessarily help you with the structure of the application, but may help you better understand what is happening on any given page.

Comment: Thanks, this helps some. What i really wish is could find is a program that would map this code into a UML or something.

Comment: UML isn't the be-all, end-all of understanding how software works. But if it helps you to have the diagrams, you could create them yourself as you learn the code.